# MUIDataTable default rows in page doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I'm trying to customize the number of rows in a `MUIDataTable`, but it seems like the default always stays at 10. This is what I tried:

```
  <MUIDataTable
      pagination="true"
      count="5"
      title={"Proposals"}
      data={data.hits}
      columns={columns}
    />
```

I also tried adding `page="1"` but it seems to have no effect. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to MUI-Datatables' [document](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables)

#### Reason

You need to provide it inside the **options** prop of your table

```
<MUIDataTable
  options={{
    count: 10,
    ...
  }}
  ...
/>
```

And `count` is correct for your demand, `page` is used for another feature

> page: User provided starting page for pagination
>   count: User provided override for total number of rows

#### Addition

By the way, you can achieve specific paging via add two related props,

> rowsPerPage: Number of rows allowed per page
>   rowsPerPageOptions: Options to provide in pagination for number of rows a user can select

Usage sample as below:

```
<MUIDataTable
  options={{
    rowsPerPage: 20,
    rowsPerPageOptions: [10, 15, 20],
    ...
  }}
  ...
/>
```